# MongoDB geoNear and group

Tags: mongodb

I tried to use geoNear and group aggregation (other options are also fine) to make the following

1. Collection has documents with `loc (2dsphere indexed)` and `user_id` field
2. There're many documents that one `user_id` has many `loc`

ex)

```
{"user_id":1, "loc": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": ... }}
{"user_id":1, "loc": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": ... }}
{"user_id":2, "loc": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": ... }}
```

3. I want to use geoNear with the last inserted `loc` s of each `user_id`

I thought it'd work with aggregation in order of group and geoNear, but the document told that geoNear must come first than others.

How could I make it?

Answer (score 0):

Citing [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#behavior):

> You can only use $geoNear as the first stage of a pipeline.

it is a current limitation of `$geoNear` in aggregation pipeline.